# UUID/GUID generator Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am promoting an affiliate offer online and the advertiser wants the GUID/IDFA info for every user  who is interested in the offer. I know there is a Javascript code that auto generates GUID.

I would like that code incorporated in my Landing page so it auto generates a GUID every time user clicks on my offer. Here's the sample offer link:

> `http://www.xxxxx.com/aff_c?offer_id=4xxx&aff_id=xxxx&source={var1}&aff_sub={clickid}&aff_sub1={campaign.id}&creative_name={var2}&creative_size={var3}&google_aid=UDID`

So once the user clicks on the offer link the UDID info is attached to the &google_aid variable.

Comment: What are your attempts? And what problems do you run into?

Comment: I am not sure how to assign the random UDID generated from within the Javascript code to &google_aid variable. Also I would want the UDID generator javascript initiated everytime a potential customer clicks on my offer link

Comment: This doesn't really answer the questions. What have you tried? How does your code look like? Do you get errors? what errors do you get? And btw, why do you want to re-initiate the UUID-generator after every click? Don't you think that it would take care of such things if it was necessary; or at least explain how to do it if you're supposed to do that yourself?

Comment: I guess the problem is I don't have a code and I don't know how to go about this. I would however pay someone for their services. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

Comment: Most guid/uuid make use of timestamp and random alphanumeric characters. Attaching the uuid as a query string to the url will depend on the front end framework you using

Answer (score 1):

You could use the algorithm from [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/guid) or, well, use that module.